# How to delete/deactivate the current PEM file and create new one in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, pem

I have hired a freelance developer to create the AWS EC2 instance,etc settings and after that he has send me the PEM file.. Although i have the PEM file, i am bit scared if he will ever misuse it in future when we go live. So i am thinking of blocking him access to my site using SSH or filezilla or any other method.

I was thinking of changing of keypair i.e. inside AWS EC2 console, i did the following - EC2 dashboard > Network & Security > Key Pairs,  deleted the existing one (Scoot1) and created a new one (Scoot2)..
But this option does not seems to work, since i can still access to the AWS backend files/code using the existing Scoot1.PEM files thru filezilla.

I would highly appreciate your advice on ;

1) if there is any other option which i can follow to secure my data of website.

2)Also, my deleting and creation of new Key Pairs, does it impact anywhere anything, which i should take care of?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have deleted the old key pair from the AWS console so it will not be used for future EC2 instances that you create, but the public key is still on the current instance. You need to replace it with your new key.

To do so, figure out what the default user name is on the instance (e.g. for Ubuntu the user is `ubuntu`, for Amazon Linux the user is `ec2-user`). In that user's home directory find the public key file (`/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`) and replace it with the updated key. That will prevent future access using the previous key.

Comment: Thanks Ben, This seems to be a good option, how do i download the new keypair from AWS, there does not seems to be any option to download.       http://i.imgur.com/vLEsSbO.png

Comment: You can only download a keypair once from the console, at the time you create it.

Comment: As i am using ubuntu and for ubuntu this file - **authorized_keys** can be located at /home/ubuntu/.ssh/ directory.

Comment: Depending on the OS, local ssh agent will cache keys. So if you add a new key, use it, then are surprised to see your old key still working, it's actually just getting ignored and ssh agent is using the new key. Fix with `ssh-add -D`.

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict access to your instance by updating security group. Restrict SSH access to your IP and developer wont be able to access your instance.

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the option i also thought of, however sometime i also work from co-work spaces and coffee-shop, so in that case it will need to keep adding the ip address or changing it everytime.. Any other option you think of please.